# How to make DLL for android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed a class in eclipse for my android application. Now I am using the same class for all my other applications. So is it possible to make that class as a dll or something which I can refer in all my applications? So if I change something in the class so I dont have to do it in my all the projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Android project as a library. This library can only contain a single class, or can contain multiple views and activities.

Then you can reference this library from different Android project, much like you would do with a DLL in a C++ application.

Check out the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) to see how you can create a library. If you're using Eclipse, this is very easy (usually 3 clics).

Answer (score 2):

No. This was actually brought up in the Google IO Android Fireside Chat yesterday, and the feature is not planned (no youtube video of the chat yet, sorry).

The closest thing you can do is set up a [Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), but then you still have to include that project in all of your other apps.

Answer (score -1):

Android likes to treat all of its applications as separate users, so it doesn't like sharing code between apps.

I would recommend just copying and pasting the completed classes.  I think you will have less trouble and less errors doing it that way instead of trying to share classes across apps.

Comment: I think the poster means while developing and not on the device